# How to call a function from a script in VUE

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using SEON SDK in my vue project (https://cdn.getdeviceinf.com/js/v5/agent.js). This  i have called in the index.html file.

Now I want to use the functions of this script(like seon.config()...) on button click.
On button click I have tried calling a function which looks like this:

```
 seon.config({
  host: "seondf.com",
  session_id: "123456abc",
  audio_fingerprint: true,
  canvas_fingerprint: true,
  webgl_fingerprint: true,
  onSuccess: function (message) {
    console.log("success", message);
  },
  onError: function (message) {
    console.log("error", message);
  },
});
```

But this is giving an error that seon not found, I have also tried this.seon, but did not work.

Can someone please guide me how can solve this problem?

SEON documentation: https://docs.seon.io/api-reference#javascript-agent-v5

Comment: could you add some documentation for SEON SDK and from where you got `seon.config()` ?

Comment: @Ankit.Z in this link https://docs.seon.io/api-reference#javascript-agent-v5 , the function is defined

Comment: It's unknown how you tried to load a script but it wasn't loaded. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem